# How to set data in child component from computed prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-multiselect

I am currently building a filter with `vue-multiselect`. Everything works, but the only problem I am facing is, that on page reload, the label (v-model) is empty.

The reason surely is, that the v-model `selectedOption` is on page reload empty, because the prop from the parent component is a computed property.

For the best readability I will cut most of the code.

**Parent component (ProductList.vue):**

```
<template>
  <section>
    <ProductListFilter v-bind:currentProductType="currentProductType"
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      currentProductType: 'shop/productTypes/currentProductType',
    }),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('shop/productTypes/setCurrentProductType', this.productType);
  },
}
</script>
```

**Child component (ProductListFilter.vue)**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-if="allProductTypes && currentProductType" class="col-4">
        <multiselect v-model="selectedProductType"
                     :options="options"
                     :multiple="false"
                     :close-on-select="true"
                     label="title"
                     placeholder="Produkttyp"
                     :allowEmpty="false">
        </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
  name: "ProductTypeFilter",
  props: ['currentProductType'],
  components: { Multiselect },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedProductType: this.currentProductType,
    }
  },  
}
</script>
```

Now the problem is, that if I print `{{ selectedProductType }}` in my template, of course it is empty because in the parent component, the property is a computed property, coming from an api. I already tried to use `this.selectedProductType = this.currentProductType` in mounted  but this does not work too,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `watch` property to update `selectedProductType` whenever `currentProductType` changes. In your child component:

```
watch: {
  currentProductType(val) {
    this.selectedProductType = val;
  }
}
```